# UITableView Delegate and DataSource methods not getting called in a custom view

Tags: ios

I created a UIView subclass, which has a tableView as a property.
I create the tableView object in the initWithFrame of the view and set its delegate and dataSource to the custom view.

I also set the scrollEnabled to NO.

and then add it as a subview.

**Result**: The tableView appears, it doesn't scroll as expected.
BUT the datasource methods are not at all getting called.
the tableView displays nothing.

I added a breakpoint inside cellForRowAtIndexPath but the control never reaches there.
I have declared the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols in the interface of the custom view.

Here's the code in initWithFrame:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.frame = frame;
        self.indexListView =  [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        self.indexListView.delegate = self;
        self.indexListView.dataSource = self;
        self.indexListView.scrollEnabled = NO;

        [self addSubview:self.indexListView];
        [self.indexListView reloadData];
        if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)])
            NSLog(@"YES.. selector is there");
    }
    return self;
}
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: didnt you forget `YourClass : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`   ?

Comment: NO.its there in the header file.

Comment: What is the return of your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: implementation ?

Comment: just realized.. its 0. count of some array. debugging now. thanks guys.

Comment: @janusfidel   Does not matter as long as the delegate and datasource routines are implemented in your delegate and/or datasource object, they will get called, regardless of the declaration of compliance in the object declaration.

Comment: Actually guys, the problem was that, the xib from which I was loading the data was in a View not a ViewController, and the array which i was configuring was in via setter.

and that was happening after view object was created and thus the created view had an empty array.

I just created the array in layoutSubviews, anyways this was some time ago but thanks.